# Software to help organize thousands of scanned documents (JPG/JPEG/PDF)

Tags: windows, images, file-management, image-viewer, pdf-viewer

I am seeking recommendations for software to help organize thousands of scanned documents.

Most are saved as JPG (JPEG) images, although some are saved as PDF files.  *It **is** okay if your recommendation only handles one of those file types.*

What I need to do is view a thumbnail of each file large enough to get a general idea of its contents.  If I can't determine the file contents by the thumbnail, I need to be able to click (or double-click) on the file to show a larger rendering.

Once I have determined the contents of the file, I need to rename it from within your recommended application.  Then I need to move the file to one of many folders in order to sort them.  I would like to be able to quickly do this for thousands of files, preferably all within a single application.

Many of the original documents had 3-8 pages, which are now stored as 3-8 separate JPG images or PDF files.  As such, the application needs to support multiple-selection when moving the files so all the files from one document can be quickly moved together.

The application must be compatible with Windows 7.  It must be free of charge (gratis) or no more than the cost of 2 milkshakes.

I have tried IrfanView and xnView to perform this task.  Although they are both excellent pieces of software, I found them lacking in their ability to perform this tedious and mind-numbing task quickly and efficiently.  If you think either of those is the best tool for the job, feel free to post that as your answer with an explanation of why you feel one of those tools is the most efficient choice.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative may be also empowering Windows Explorer using additional tools, or "shell addons".

**Seer's** [website](http://1218.io/) boast the functionality of:

> A Windows quick look tool. Acts just like the one in macOS, but Seer
>   is more powerful, customizable and faster.

This tool achieves your requirements with the following feature:

- It can handle working with thousands of files, renaming, and working with different kinds of files, such as PNG, JPG, or PDF.

Explorer's downfall is actually glancing at the files quickly, but you can solve that with a little program called [Seer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ccseer/).

Seer gives you "Mac-like" previews for Windows Explorer so you can see what is in the file before opening it:

[image: Screenshot Preview]

This might not be perfect for your needs, but I thought it might be a consideration for you.  Hope it helps!

Comment: Hey LinkChef, jus FYI - http://1218.io/seer.html

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Adobe Bridge CC](http://www.adobe.com/products/bridge.html). It has thumbnails for JPG and PDF, plus a preview pane, plus full screen preview, and you can open the file from Bridge. It allows you to rename (with preview open) and move multiple files at one time. It is free of charge.

Comment: Thanks.  Based on complaints of blurriness in your question https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/38760/document-management-software-to-preview-and-rename-pdfs would you still recommend it?

Comment: Yes, since your request was for it to be "large enough to get a general idea of its contents." In my scenario, I wanted to be able to be able to zoom in and view crisp text on a pdf. So, for my use case, it did not work. However, I think it would work for you.