# Document management software to preview and rename PDFs

Tags: pdf, document-management, file-preview

I am looking for document management software that can specifically (A) preview PDFs at full resolution and (B) rename those PDFs while the preview is open.

I tried using Adobe Bridge CC but the PDF previews are blurry. Windows Explorer with the preview pane works, but our end users do not like switching between Full Screen/Preview On ("document management mode") and Restored/Preview Off ("normal file management").

An added benefit would be quick access to file description/metadata.

For reference, files are hosted on a Synology NAS and end users are all using Windows 10.

Comment: Do you have a server which is running all the time? If yes, some solutions exist that generate and store the previews, and allow users to rename files without having to download the full files. The way files are stored would change a bit though. Is that acceptable?

Comment: I have a Synology NAS that's running all the time, but no other type of server (e.g. Windows Server). That sounds like it would be acceptable.